# Regular Expression Deinal of Service: hosted-git-info

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, npm

I have an Ionic/Angular app. It shows below vulnerability. Can you tell me how to fix that?

Here it says to update the latest version of `hosted-git-info`. But I can't see such a package on my `package.json` file. https://www.npmjs.com/advisories/1677

```
Moderate        Regular Expression Deinal of Service                          

  Package         hosted-git-info                                               

  Patched in      >=3.0.8                                                       

  Dependency of   eslint-plugin-import [dev]                                    

  Path            eslint-plugin-import > read-pkg-up > read-pkg >               
                  normalize-package-data > hosted-git-info                      

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1677

found 1 moderate severity vulnerability in 1800 scanned packages
  1 vulnerability requires manual review. See the full report for details.
```

Answer (score 1):

Sampath, this package is into the package: eslint-plugin-import. I was seeing in that project it: [Github Vulnerability](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/issues/2046)

Other users are opening an issue to resolve it because the latest version was released 7 months ago. So we need to wait for the package to be updated :c

Comment: Yes. ref: https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/issues/2046

Comment: Hmm.. No solution from them?https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/issues/2046#issuecomment-833778983

Comment: It seems yes, they just gave up :c

Comment: It is not. We have a hope now: https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/issues/2046#issuecomment-833795724

Comment: Nice, they fixed our problem xD

Answer (score 1):

While they are upgrading their package you can add `hosted-git-info` as a resolution to your `package.json`:

```
"resolutions": {
    ...
    "hosted-git-info": ">=3.0.8",
    ...
}
```

This forces any usage of `hosted-git-info` in packages to be above the stated version.